# Android - Reference resource drawable as a URL

Tags: android

I'm using an API in my Android app that downloads images from the web and shows a placeholder animation while the images are downloading (RemoteImageView, part of the Ignition package [here](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition).

At some points in the app, I need to show images from the local resource drawables and not downloaded from the web.

Is it possible to access the local resource drawables using a URL ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Local image resources do not have urls, they have URIs. So if you have image in drawable, you can parse them from resource id to URI.

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("R.drawable.image");
```

However, if you can also put your images in asset folder of the package and access them using their URL. The URL of the image files would be "file:///android_asset/image.png"
You can use either of the option.

Comment: Uri.parse is saying that R.drawable.image should be a String. That can't be right ??

Comment: Woops, forgot to add quotes. Corrected now.

Comment: Nope... neither work. I think the API is making a connection through URLConnection and I have to pass it a String representation of the URL. Uri.parse().toString() just give back the original String... and its not finding it with the file:///android_asset/.. path either

Comment: Try to parse your image file using the following syntax into Uri.parse() "android.resource://[package]/[res id]", for eg. - Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example/" + R.drawable.image);

Comment: Nah... nothing. I think I'll have to hack the API to display the drawable directly from resources instead of accessing it through a URLConnection

Comment: Is it possible to do the vice versa; get the resource drawable from the URI?

Comment: Something is wrong with the sentence: "However, IF you can also....".  Looks like we are missing the "THEN" part  (i.e. IF X THEN Y).

Answer (score 18):

The way to do it:

use this line `"android.resource://[your package]/"+[res id]`

Here is an example

```
Uri myURI = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.project/" + R.drawable.myimage);
```

for convenient you can use it as a method:

```
public static Uri getUrl(int res){
  return Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.project/" + res);
}
```

**Warning** do not use `context.getPackageName()` as substitute to package name because it might return a null value.

Comment: In what cases does it return null after your app has initialized? If you don't load it programatically, then builds that change the package will break the code.

Comment: Why don't use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID?

Comment: @CristianGomez feel free to use BuildConfig, this answer was made 3 years ago (kinda outdated) and my IDE that time is Eclipse and Gradle is not something I am familiar with that time. The important part here is knowing the Uri that resembles the resource location.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work.  I got no error message when loading via Glide, it simply didn't load.