# How can get internal url of an image from drawable folder in Android studio/java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable

How to use stored images in drawable folder in java code?

I store file in this path: `res/drawble/img.jpg`

look:

in .xml I call images in this way:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_arrow_back"
```

currently I have a function uses external images URL:

```
//function 
imgprocess('http://www.google.com/img.jpg')
```

Now! I do not want use an external images link. Because I want my application works offline.

So I saved img.jpg in `drawable` folder and then and try call it in java code like this:

```
//function 
imgprocess(@drawable/img)
```

Ok. I know this code is wrong.

All answers suggest use [Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)
But I can not understand why is it answer? It just give me a none string id. Also I do not have a ImageView or TextView in none of my xml files. I do not need them. I just want java code access to that image directly.

for example this code return name of img:

```
String resourceName = getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.img);
```

So I think It must there a function to return path of images to use in java, I know below code is wrong but something like this:

```
String resourceURL = getResources().getResourceURL(R.drawable.img);
```

I hope I explained my problem clear. how the function can access the images from my drawable folder directly as a internal link?

---

for example in HTML `<img src="http://google.com/img.jpg">`  is an external images...and you can easily save image in root folder and call this in this way: `<img src="img.jpg">` ...

Comment: I think this has been answered already

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296999/android-reference-resource-drawable-as-a-url

Comment: @Lukas Elsner / I think it is wrong. because my function accept string and uri it is not string. I try convert it `uri.tostring()` but it not work. I printed it. it just print `R.drawble.img`

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is your expected result? I think the other question pretty much explains how to resolve a local URI from a resource.

```
public static Uri getUrl(int res){
  return Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.project/" + res);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thats what i wanted to do. It seems I was quite a bit confused about the interface here, since my first answer was automatically converted into a comment. I probably just hit the wrong button!

Answer (score 0):

URL is not for Drawable it is URI, here an example method using the filename

```
public static Uri getUrl(String filename){
   return Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.project/drawable/"+filename);
}
```

Other example, URI from the SDcard of your device.

```
Uri myURI = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/monsterdog.jpg"));
```